# schm-reduplication (yiddish) morphological process

Tags: prolog

By definition, **schm-reduplication** is a form of reduplication in which the original word or its first syllable (the base) is repeated with the copy (the reduplicant) beginning with shm-.

```
baby -> schmaby
sprinkler -> schminkler
artist -> schmartist
```

So all of the letters up till the first vowel of the word are removed with a 'schm' prepended to it.

How do translate this into code?

I'm thinking..

(1) Get the list. (2) Remove all elements until the first vowel is detected. So I'm thinking this will be useful: `vowel(X):- member(X,[a,e,i,o,u]).` So I would need to scan first element to the end and once I get to a vowel, I keep that and prepend a 'schm'.

I'm having trouble with the removing all elements till vowel part. Can someone help?

I have:

```
yiddish(A,B):-
append([s,c,h,m],A,B).

?- yiddish([h,o,u,s,e],X).
X = [s, c, h, m, h, o, u, s, e].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your schema could be implemented like

```
yiddish(A,B) :- after_first_vowel(A,AFV), append([s,c,h,m],AFV,B).

% here some decision should be taken about data correctness
after_first_vowel([C|Cs],[C|Cs]) :- memberchk(C,[a,e,i,o,u]), !.
after_first_vowel([_|Cs],Rs) :- after_first_vowel(Cs,Rs).
```

basic test:

```
?- atom_chars(baby,Cs),yiddish(Cs,L).
Cs = [b, a, b, y],
L = [s, c, h, m, a, b, y]
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, what can i do to increase the 'length capacity'? For example, `atom_chars(trousers,Cs),yiddish(Cs,L).
Cs = [t, r, o, u, s, e, r, s], L = [s, c, h, m, o, u, s, e, r|...].` but it doesn't truncate if it's just `trouser`. I don't see the restriction of 7 characters in your code, so I'm curious what it could be.

Comment: no problem, it's a user interface feature of the interpreter: when a list is longer than a configurable limit, only the first elements are shown. Try for instance `?- atom_chars(trousers,Cs),yiddish(Cs,L),write(L).`

Comment: Ah ok, you're right. It displays differently between SWI-Prolog and gprolog. I've also noticed that some libraries in SWI-Prolog do not work with gprolog; the predicate 'intersection' for example. Anyway, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @am3decoy different implementations of Prolog (SWI, GNU, SICStus, ...) have their own libraries. They have many in common, but many unique ones as well. There is an [ISO standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=21413) for Prolog (also described [here](http://www.deransart.fr/prolog/docs.html) which the various implementations have different degrees of compliance to.

Comment: @lurker: so sad `Last Changed: 1999/06/14`, and still no agreement on basic features...

Comment: @CapelliC indeed. Lack of a strong standards base, in part, encourages the diversity of implementations.